# What are you supposed to do with the Giant Ant in the Gutter?

Tags: dark-souls-2

While exploring the gutter I bumped into a giant ant that seems to constantly spit an harmless gas. You can lock it, so it seems an enemy, but it doesn't hit back on you if attacked. I tried to google about it but I wasn't satisfied by what I've read.

What's the purpose of this Ant? Is there a way to interact with it? Killing it would/would not trigger events?

Answer (score 6):

If you kill it, you're able to walk into the room it was blocking to find a few Poison Moss.

It has no known significance otherwise. It's not possible to converse with it using the Ring of Whispers, either.

Comment: No NG+ use is known?

Comment: Not that I've ever heard. If something ever does get discovered, I would love for someone to post an answer to that effect to educate us.

Comment: The gas does little more than slightly increasing the rate at which you recover from the poison status effect.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently according to [this reddit post](http://www.reddit.com/r/DarkSouls2/comments/21ipgw/psa_the_mystery_of_the_gutter_ant_solved/), it will puff out blue smoke which cures poison. I haven't been able to try this myself yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a theory that I didn't test more than twice, but everytime I walked into the gas it spits out and out, the statues no longer shot poison at me.

Comment: tested today, did not work for me

Answer (score -1):

It cures the poison status affect with the gas it spits out